# Two way communication between publisher and consumers

Tags: android, rabbitmq

All the documentations I've read so far talked about different ways of communicating between one publisher and multiple consumers - publisher publishes messages to a single queue or multiple, and consumers consume them in different ways depending on how you set it up. My requirement is two way communications between publisher and consumers using single queue, and I'm wondering if it could be achieved using RabbitMq. To elaborate, my requirement is that - multiple clients are subscribed to a queue, and a client becomes a publisher when it needs to publish a message and send a message to the queue. Other times, clients are just consumers pooling the same queue. Is that possible with RMQ?

Comment: How did you fixed that? please post your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. A client should have at least two connections to RabbitMQ - one for publishing, and one for consuming. Then channels can be set up on each connection and away you go. Obviously multi-threading or other concurrent programming techniques are necessary.